# wait keyword missing in Python socketio

Tags: python, sockets, flask, python-socketio

Below is the code for connecting to server using python-socketio

```
import socketio
sio_bot = socketio.Client(logger =True,engineio_logger =True)
sio_bot.connect(IP,wait=False)
```

but I am getting an error as below

```
sio_bot.connect(IP,wait=False)
TypeError: connect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'wait'
```

The documentation mentions the **wait** keyword
https://python-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

The version of python is 3.6 and the version of python-socketio is python-socketio==4.6.0

Please let me know what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The version of python is 3.6 and the version of python-socketio is python-socketio==4.6.0
>
> Please let me know what am I missing?

You missed the [Change Log](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/blob/master/CHANGES.md):

> **Release 5.1.0** - 2021-03-10
>
> Added `wait` argument to client's connect method